# Add days to Outlook email flag due date

Tags: vba, outlook

How to change the following Outlook macro from adding 7 days to `Now`, to adding it to the item due date?

```
    Dim objMsg As Object

   ' GetCurrent Item function is at http://slipstick.me/e8mio
    Set objMsg = GetCurrentItem()
    With objMsg
       ' due this week flag
       .MarkAsTask olMarkThisWeek
       ' sets a specific due date
       .TaskDueDate = Now + 7
       '   .FlagRequest = "Call " & objMsg.SenderName
       .ReminderSet = False
       '   .ReminderTime = Now + 2
       .Save
    End With

    Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the following:

```
.TaskDueDate = .TaskDueDate + 7
```

---

```
.TaskDueDate = DateAdd("d", 7, .TaskDueDate)
```

Comment: Already tried both before and failed. But upon your solution checked again and remarked .MarkAsTask olMarkThisWeek and now is working. Interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Try below function :-

```
DateAdd("d", 7, Now)
```

Comment: 7 days from item due date, not "Now"

Comment: It was for your help as an example. You can put any date you want in place of "NOW".

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Now + 7 use Date + 7.
This will add 7 days to present date.

Comment: 7 days from item due date, not present day.